# Create email hyperlink in text string for C# textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox that I add pre-prepared strings to.  Some of those strings contain email addresses and I would like to have those addresses open my default email client when clicked.  I've tried prepending mailto: to those addresses and it does cause the address to be highlighted in the text box, which is good, but clicking it does nothing. I've seen articles on adding such links directly to a text box but my situation is such that I must pre-prepare an entire string containing the address as just part of it, then add that entire string at once to the text box.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: You'll need to create a Hyperlink instance with this content, and add it to RichTextBox in a InlineUIContainer

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I was somehow thinking I'd have to do something special to the text itself but that is obviously not the case.